# How to use Angular templating to string

Tags: angular

In order to send emails (external api) I need to render the email-body with dynamic content in them from Angular.

So now my component loads an external html file from a URL into a string.

```
const response =  await fetch(path);
const html = await response.text();
```

Somehow I would like to use Angular's templating system so I can do things like {{ model.name }} and *ngIf etc. inside the HTML template.

It doesn't need to output to the screen, only return a string which I then can send to the mailsender.

Is this possible? I just can't find how to do this. All I find is to put it on the screen.

Or should I just use some external templating engine? But that feels somewhat stupid as Angular basically does this...

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: IMHO, in most cases, email rendering should be moved to server side, angular only provides email context.

Comment: Browser only understand HTML,JS and CSS. if you wanna to achieve this kind of functionality you need to Javascript. Angular will not work over here

Comment: @AnkurShah I mean the Angular templating engine. My code happens in an Angular component, so I would think I could use that engine in code.